# AEM 6.5 xf page not self-refreshed after authoring is done

Tags: aem

AEM Version : 6.5.12

Problem

1. Where : at experience-fragment page
2. When : Authoring any component(insert/update/edit/delete)
3. What happens : 
   (1) POST xhr request sent from AEM editor is not getting any response. 
   (2) Editor Page is not changed automatically, but when I refresh it manually, authored contents are updated.

Note : This problem **only occurs in Experience-fragment** editor page(even with we.retail xf pages), NOT in sites editor.

I need help with this problem. thanks.

I think POST request is sent correctly to AEM server, because Authoring jobs are done. I guess response is not correctly sent back to browser, so editor callback function is not fired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem myself.

What I checked :

- AEM > Tools > Operations > Health Reports > **Asynchronous Indexes**
- It was "Critical" Status, with this message "The 'async' indexing lane is failing."
- At crx/de, under "oak:index" node, there was 3 nodes had "corrupt" property.
- I reindexed those nodes -> corrupt property removed
- AEM > Tools > Operations > Health Reports > Asynchronous Indexes Status became "OK" and problem solved.